# Spark - speed up code generation

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any way to speed up code generation for complex SQL queries in spark? I imagine this is like a compilation/optimization type problem. I run the same queries on the same schema every day - is it possible to save compiled queries such that this happens only once?

Comment: What version of Spark? You could try upgrading to the latest, but there's no concept of a "prepared statement" for the sql engine that I know of

Comment: Version `2.2.0` which I think is fairly fresh

Comment: there is no such concept in spark unfortunately

Comment: That makes me :(

Comment: Yeah, Spark2 improves the SQL execution a lot. I feel like the only way to optimize a Spark or Hive query is to write it differently, like most SQL queries. Maybe store the file sets differently to begin with. Even if you read a Hive table with a predefined schema, it still needs to parse the raw data on disk.

Comment: Oh I know. I don't like most of the queries. But such is life.

Comment: the reason it's not available is that Spark isn't a RDBMS, so we can't treat it like one. spark-sql DSL queries are just "syntaxic sugars"